# Flutter: Can anyone tell me the names of these packages?

Tags: flutter

```
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/gallery_localizations.dart';
    import 'package:gallery/demos/material/material_demo_types.dart';
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text(GalleryLocalizations.of(context).buttonText),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 12),
          ElevatedButton.icon(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.add, size: 18),
            label: Text(GalleryLocalizations.of(context).buttonText),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Flutter code generator for your assets, fonts, colors [flutter_gen](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_gen)

Flutter Gallery is a resource to help developers evaluate and use Flutter
[link](https://github.com/flutter/gallery)